# Use the method of cylindrical shells to find the volume about $y = 8, 8y = x^3, y = 0, x = 4$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm so stuck on this problem and I have no idea where I'm making a mistake.  Please help me if you can.

So here is my function and the bounds:

$$8y=x^3, y=0, x=4$$

About the line $y=8$

First thing I did was make $x$ a function of $y$.

$$x = 2y^\frac{1}{3}$$

I found the radius to be:
$$radius=8-y$$
$$height=8-2y^\frac{1}{3}$$

The one part I was confused by is where the bounds of my integral would be.  So I figured they would be the bounds of $x$.  So I setup my integral this way:

$$2\pi\int_{0}^{4}(8-y)(8-2y^\frac{1}{3})dy$$

I simplified this to be:

$$4\pi\int_{0}^{4}(32-8y^\frac{1}{3}-4y+y^\frac{4}{3})dy$$

I figure there is no point outlining the rest of my steps if I didn't even setup the integral right, so is this part correct?  If it is, I will edit my post with the remaining integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine up through your calculation of the radius of the shell at $y$. The height, however, is wrong, as is the upper limit of integration. I suspect that you’ve been misled by the term *height*. These cylindrical shells have a horizontal axis, the line $y=8$, so their height is measured horizontally. The righthand edge of the region is the line $x=4$, and the lefthand edge is the curve $x=2y^{1/3}$, so the height of the shell at $y$ is $4-2y^{1/3}$, not $8-2y^{1/3}$. And the $y$ values at which the shells are taken run from $y=0$ at the bottom to $y=8$ at the top: the uppermost point of the region is $\langle 4,8\rangle$.

Make those corrections, and you should be in business.